# Limesurvey alternative for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, survey, limesurvey

Does anyone know of a full featured survey  tool for rails? Like Limesurvey (PHP -unfortunately for my purposes.)? Tried to look on Ruby-toolbox, but it seems to be down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on GitHub?

http://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=ruby&q=survey&repo=&langOverride=&x=10&y=19&start_value=1

Comment: Based on that search the best options on GitHub are:

(1) https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor - a gem/plugin to add to an existing rails app
(2) https://github.com/yzhang/ThunderSurvey - a full rails app for surveys

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an online survey/test framework. Limesurvey works but the code and database design does not fit for my purpose.

http://github.com/gurix/helena